# Ubuntu 20.04 text editor jump

Tags: mouse, cursor, text-editor, qt-creator

If I'm writing in Qt Creator and go to firefox do some browsing, tab switching and go back to Qt Creator, sometimes the cursor jumps and scrolls to some random location (I think to the top) which is ultra disturbing while programming.
Not sure if it is related to QTC or Ubuntu or Keyboard or Mouse.
Is there some procedure to figure out where the command comes from in order to fix it?

Update: I found out how to reproduce it: In QTC you scroll down, without clicking (= without moving the cursor to this position), open any other window. If you click on QTC again, it will jump back to where the cursor is.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to Qt Creator, I moved from 4.4.2 to 7.0.2 and it's not happening again.